# What are the different columns in this Terminal display?

Tags: terminal

I am wondering what the different columns are in this attached screenshot of the Terminal window. The command line that I typed into Terminal is:

```
ls -l ~/Desktop
```

It is the command for the computer to bring up all of the files that are located on the Desktop. There is another column to the right with the file names. I left that out of the screenshot for privacy purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From left to right, the columns are: [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) (e.g., read, write, execute), then the number of links, the owning user of the file, the owning group of the file, the file size (bytes for files, 512 byte blocks for directories), and the last time the file was accessed. The column you didn't show on the far right is the name of the file in question.

For future reference, you can always run `man <command>` to find information about a command. So in this case, `man ls` will provide the information you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I had another question. In the column that shows when the last time that the file was accessed was, some of them have the month, day, and year. Others have the month, day, and time. Why is that?

Comment: According to the `man` page, "If the modification time of the file is more than 6 months in the past or future, then the year of the last modification is displayed in place of the hour and minute fields."

Comment: @ChrisS: The default is for the file size to be in bytes not 512 byte blocks. Also, *"number of links to other files"* is wrong. The value is the total number of directory entries (links).

Comment: Yeah, I had bytes originally, but then got confused by the statement about blocks on directories. I'll made an edit. Could you clarify the difference on our statements on links? Is it because every file links to itself?

Comment: @ChrisS: When a file is create, the file is assigned an inode number unique to the file stored in the volume. When a directory entry is made, the directory entry is assigned the inode number of the file. This inode number does not have to be unique to that directory entry. The "number of links" value shown for a file in the output of `ls -l` is the total count of directory entries that have been assigned the file's inode number. To see the inode numbers you would need to enter `ls -i`.

Comment: You may have been assuming there is a one-to-one correspondence between a directory entry and a file, which is not true unless the "number of links" value is 1. For most files, this value is 1.